# Why isn't the class Type sealed, and what can I do with that?

Tags: c#, inheritance, types

I was looking at the metadata for Type, and noticed a member was protected, which made me wonder what might derive from it, which made me realize I could write a class that derives from it, and all that makes me wonder what I can do with that (if anything).

No compiler error from following:

```
class MyType : Type
{
    // Implemented abstract members here.
}
```

Comment: Very interesting question! But please remove that unnecessary code block, it doesn't really add more value to your question than just `class MyType : Type { ... }`.

Comment: i'll let someone with edit priv who agrees with you do it, i think its ineresting to see what a derived class must implement in order to compile...

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Great question. I only have a partial answer. There are currently 4 classes that derive from Type. You can find the Type hierarchy on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.aspx).

```
System.Object
  System.Reflection.MemberInfo
    System.Type
      System.Reflection.Emit.EnumBuilder
      System.Reflection.Emit.GenericTypeParameterBuilder
      System.Reflection.Emit.TypeBuilder
      System.Reflection.TypeDelegator
```

It looks like those types are basically used to encapsulate some "instance-building" logic. But I haven't explored the code.

*Edit*

Oh, wow... that's interesting. The code examples seem to not only be creating *instances* of types, but also *classes* themselves. Therefore, some of these classes are creating CLR types, and saving them off to real assemblies. That's pretty cool.

*Edit Again*

Some of the big dogs have said that there are more than the four types I listed above. I used <s>Reflector</s> ReSharper to find the derived types and found these (there could still be types missing):

```
System.Type
  System.RuntimeType
  System.ReflectionOnlyType
  System.Reflection.Emit.EnumBuilder
  System.Reflection.Emit.GenericTypeParameterBuilder
  System.Reflection.Emit.SymbolType
  System.Reflection.Emit.TypeBuilder
  System.Reflection.Emit.TypeBuilderInstantiation
  System.Reflection.TypeDelegator
```

*Edit Once More*

as @MarcGravell stated, there's really no reason why you would want to derive a class from any of these. You could, however, use them within a class of your own to encapsulate your own logic.

Comment: just a guess, but maybe when you "pre compile" a regular expression, that is what happens behind the scenes

Comment: yeah, the meta-programming is very strong in .NET; I have some code that does really crazy things with that

Answer (score 7):

Yeah, don't inherit from that ;p There are things like `RuntimeType` etc - `Type` is the abstraction you should usually use. If you want to represent a type dynamically at runtime, there are 2 main options;

- in 4.0, `dynamic` (via implementing `IDynamicMetaObjectProvider`)
- before that, `TypeDescriptor` (via implementing `ICustomTypeDescriptor` or providing a `TypeDescriptionProvider`, and possibly a `TypeConverter`)

If you want to do meta-programming (creating actual new types at runtime, rather than spoofing it), there is also `TypeBuilder`

Comment: Would there be any reason to inherit from Type at all? The code examples on MSDN show some of the derived types being used to encapsulate some class-creation logic (such as the EnumBuilder). Would it be logical to use Type, or TypeBuilder as a base class for generating other types or assemblies?

Comment: @ChristopherHarris the "builder" versions aren't actually *usable*; they are meta-programming only. It is only when `CreateType()` is used to create an *actual* type (known only as `Type`) that they are usable

Comment: Right, I see that now. Would it be appropriate (hypothetically) to create more "builder" versions, use just use the existing builder versions?

Comment: @ChristopherHarris no, there isn't much useful you can do by sublassing this, except really confusing the system. I don't recommend it.

Answer (score 7):

`Type` is unsealed because it's actually designed to be inherrited from by the runtime.  There are many examples of this in the BCL

- EnumBuilder
- RuntimeType
- TypeBuilder

The most interesting of these, IMHO, is `RuntimeType`  This is how a good majority of the `Type` instances in a running system are implmented.  Most calls to `o.GetType()` will actually return a `RuntimeType` instance.